# How to change/fake the 'file size' on the fly in C code

Tags: c, filesystems, size, filesize, stat

I am working on user level filesystem using FUSE and my requirement is that :

- When I issue read for `File A`, I want to superimpose the contents of another file (say `File B`) and present the contents of `File B` as `File A`'s contents.
- I have already achieved it by buffer modifications by capturing it in my fuse read and internally reading `File B` and copying the buffer contents to the passed in buffer for `File A` and not doing any actual read call for `File A`. So, `File A` call returns with `File B`'s contents copied in its buffer.
- Also, `File A` is of smaller size compared to `File B`.

When checked using debugger, `File A` buffer contents look fine (contains whole of `File B` contents), but when it gets displayed (say with `Vi`) for `File A`, I am able to see only those many characters as the `File A`'s size, but as `File B` size is more, the whole data never gets shown even if the returned buffer to `File A` (the `File B` data copied) has more to display. This is because `File A` size is smaller and the display terminates when character count is reached for `File A`'s filesize.

I tried looking into `struct stat`, but it is a read-only thing which shows me the size of `File A` which is smaller compared to `File B`.

```
struct stat stat1;
stat(fileA, &stat1);
```

So, my question is that how do I fake/change the size of `File A` on-the-fly, so that it is able to display whole the data (which got superimposed because `File B` was bigger).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this because many applications request file size before reading the file and then read only the reported amount of data.